# R: run a python function with reticulate passing arguments as R variables (need r_to_py()?)

Tags: python, r, type-conversion, arguments, reticulate

I am using the Python program [stitchr](https://github.com/JamieHeather/stitchr) inside an R package, so I run it with `reticulate`.

I follow the instructions listed [here](https://jamieheather.github.io/stitchr/importing.html).

I create a file "run_stitchr.py" with these contents:

```
# import stitchr
from Stitchr import stitchrfunctions as fxn
from Stitchr import stitchr as st

# specify details about the locus to be stitched
chain = 'TRB'
species = 'HUMAN'

# initialise the necessary data
tcr_dat, functionality, partial = fxn.get_imgt_data(chain, st.gene_types, species)
codons = fxn.get_optimal_codons('', species)

# provide details of the rearrangement to be stitched
tcr_bits = {'v': 'TRBV7-3*01', 'j': 'TRBJ1-1*01', 'cdr3': 'CASSYLQAQYTEAFF',
            'l': 'TRBV7-3*01', 'c': 'TRBC1*01',
            'skip_c_checks': False, 'species': species, 'seamless': False,
            '5_prime_seq': '', '3_prime_seq': '', 'name': 'TCR'}

# then run stitchr on that rearrangement
stitched = st.stitch(tcr_bits, tcr_dat, functionality, partial, codons, 3, '')
```

And I just run it like:

```
stitchr_results <- reticulate::py_run_file("run_stitchr.py")
```

This works perfect, but I want to try and get rid of that .py file, and instead produce the inputs needed in R, and pass them as arguments to the main function `st.stitch()` (as specified in the .py file).

This is my best attempt:

```
fxn <- reticulate::import("Stitchr.stitchrfunctions")
st <- reticulate::import("Stitchr.stitchr")
chain <- "TRB"
species <- "HUMAN"
output <- fxn$get_imgt_data(chain, st$gene_types, species)
tcr_dat <- output[[1]]
functionality <- output[[2]]
partial <- output[[3]]
codons <- fxn$get_optimal_codons('', species)
tcr_bits <- list(v = 'TRBV7-3*01',
                 j = 'TRBJ1-1*01',
                 cdr3 = 'CASSYLQAQYTEAFF',
                 l = 'TRBV7-3*01',
                 c = 'TRBC1*01',
                 skip_c_checks = 'False',
                 species = species,
                 seamless = 'False',
                 '5_prime_seq' = '',
                 '3_prime_seq' = '',
                 name = 'TCR')
stitched <- st$stitch(tcr_bits, tcr_dat, functionality, partial, codons, 3, '')
```

... but I get this:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, call_args$unnamed, call_args$named) : 
  KeyError: 'TRBV7-3'
```

I'm not very proficient with Python, but I suspect I need to convert the R variables into Python types (`reticulate::r_to_py()`?), but I tried every possibility I could think of, and still it does not work (note that all arguments are python lists, like `tcr_bits` in the .py file).

If anyone can shed some light here, I would appreciate it!
Many thanks.